# Missing activator-dist directory which is required for Java Play Project

Tags: java, playframework, build, sbt

Can anyone give me some information about **activator-dist** directory? I recently switched to a new Mac, in my old mac outside the workspace directory there was another directory **activator-dist-1.3.12**. I don't recall creating this directory, also that was a long time back and I was at the beginners' phase of learning Play Framework; so I don't remember much about the setup. The build of my project is done by SBT, and it is a Java Play Project.

There are couple of questions I want to ask -

1. First, Is this directory automatically gets created by running some
   command? If yes then what is the command?
2. Second, If it doesn't get
   automatically created then should I copy the same directory from the
   old Mac to the new Mac?

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to run the test of the project:

> Error:scalac: Scala compiler JARs not found (module 'root'):
>   Documents/<*location*>/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.6/jars/scala-library.jar

By this error, I am getting the sense that this directory contains all the important jars which are required for building the project, other than that is there any significance of this directory that I should be aware of?

Comment: Which version of Play you are using?

Comment: My play version is 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**activator-dist**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing#Install-Activator) is a package which provides the build tool(sbt) and other helper items. If you want to create and build a Play project then you need activator, it should be downloaded on the local machine and add the bin directory path inside the activator directory to the environment path.

For Play <= 2.5 versions activator is recommended, for Play 2.6 onwards recommended way is using [sbt](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayConsole)